# Candidate elimination algorithm lecture example

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, candidate

I am looking through some lecture slides and cannot understand why the bold hypothesis at last G are just discarded, I can come to the same answer but don't understand why they're just discarded.

```
   sky           temperature         humidity
 |     |        |          |        |       |
Sunny  Rainy      Warm       Coo     Normal   Low
```

and the set of positive and negative training examples:

```
    1.      ( S W N )+)
    2.      ( R C L )-)
    3 .     ( S C N )+)
    4.      ( S W L )-)
```

Training with the first example: ( S W N ) +)  generalizing…

G = [( ? ? ? )]
S = [( S W N )]

Training with the second example: ( R C L ) -)  specializing…

G = [( S ? ? ) ( ? W ? ) ( ? ? N )
S = [( S W N )]

Training with the third example: ( S C N ) +) generalizing…

G = [( S ? ? )( ? ? N )]                              *(the other is discarded )*
S = [( S ? N )]

Training with the fourth example: ( S W L ) -)  specializing…

G = [**( S C ? )**( S ? N )**( R ? N )(? C N)**]  *(bold are discarded )*
S = [( S ? N )]

Convergence, the learned concept must be:  [( S ? N )]

Comment: Can you give as a link to the slides?

Comment: Slides are word document and password protected, this was everything useful from the question

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> G = [( **S C ?** )( S ? N )( **R ? N** )(**? C N**)] (bold are discarded )

It can be simply using the candidate elimination algorithm. According to that the reasons can be summarized as follows.

1. Inconsistent hypothesis: According to the algorithm we have to first remove the hypotheses which are not consistent with target data(D)

   In this case ( **R ? N** ) is removed it's inconsistent with ( S ? N )
2. Specific boundary being more general than the general boundary.

   If the specific boundy become more specific that the general one. There can be a boundary overlapping.

   if we compare derived ( **S C ?** ) with ( S ? N ) , we can compare middle c with ? of (S ? N).  The derived one having a constant makes it more specific compared to the specific boundary. So it should be removed. Same goes with (**? C N**).

I see the question is bit older but I hope someone would find this useful.